# the associated action on the transition functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a curve with an involution $\sigma$ generically unramified, given a $G-$bundle $E$ of rank $r$, than we ca take its pull-back, I want to describe the action of $\sigma$ on $G$. Fix a linearization $$a:\sigma^*\mathcal O_X^{\oplus r}\rightarrow \mathcal O_X^{\oplus r}$$ than if $\{g_{i,j}\}$ are the associated transition functions, I got that $\{a^{-1}\circ g_{i,j}\circ a\}$ are the transition functions of $\sigma^* E$. 
I am not convinced by this, for example, if we take $G=GL_r$ I don't see how this action is? How can we describe this action in this particular case? How $a$ act on $GL_r$?

Is it possible to get a covering stable by $\sigma$ which trivialize $E$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If we pullback a local chart : $\phi_i:E|_{U_i}\rightarrow U_i\times \mathbb C^r$ we get $\sigma ^*\phi_i=a^{-1}\circ \phi_i\circ b$, where $a$ is as above, and $b:\sigma^*E|_{U_i}\rightarrow E|_{U_i}$ but then the local chart of the pullback is $\phi_i\circ b$ , I know that $b$ is not a bundle map, so this confuse me!!! is $\phi_i\circ b$ a bundle map?